# How to create or copy symbolic link in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Good afternoon.

I am trying to create a symbolic link to another trunk in Tortoise SVN.

It doesn't seem like there is an option to create a symbolic link anywhere in the repo browser.

I tried copying links from other projects, but it seems the repo browser only allows me to copy links into further directoy levels, not in previous directory. Like if I had a file in /svn/project1/link1, it would let me copy into /svn/project1/folder/link1, but it would not let me copy into /svn/project2/link1.

Why is Tortoise SVN so limiting?

When I try to copy using Copy To command in the repo browser, I get the error: *Source and destination URLs appear not to point to the same repository.* 
Even though both projects are located on the same SVN server.

I am using the newest version of Tortoise I just downloaded today.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Read SVN Book about externals feature and it's current limitation.

In common: you can use file-based externals inside common repository, but only directory-based externals in cross-repositories definition